# VBA Type mismatch error on Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""

Tags: vba, excel

Hey I've got code moving rows out to another sheet with the name of the cell, a loop until it hits a blank at the end of the data, an extract of the code here;

```
Range("AF2").Select
Do While ActiveCell.Value <> ""
    strDestinationSheet = ActiveCell.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -31).Resize(1, ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Columns.count).Select
    Selection.Copy

    Sheets(strDestinationSheet).Select
    N = Cells(Rows.count, "AF").End(xlUp).Row
    lastRow = N

    Cells(lastRow + 1, 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Sheets(strSourceSheet).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 31).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
```

However while this part of the code worked fine before on the latest instance of running it now throws up an error on the second line Do While ActiveCell.Value <> "", saying type mismatch. I'm unsure of what's changed to stop this working suddenly, any ideas? Many thanks.

Comment: You probably have an error in one of the cells.

Comment: Thanks Scott there are indeed some #N/As on the column, could I just put an error trap to skip when it encounters these? Where exactly would that need to go?

Comment: (It's also highly recommended to [avoid using `.Select`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros))

Comment: Your code will be much easier to follow/read and maintain/debug, if you properly indent it.

Answer (score 4):

I personally do not like Do Loops to iterate through a group of cells.  I prefer the For Each loop.

Also as was stated by @bruceWayne, avoid using Select as is slows down the code.

Proper indentation makes the code easier to read and avoid simple mistakes.

```
Dim cel As Range
With Sheets(strSourceSheet)
    For Each cel In .Range("AF2", .Range("AF2").End(xlDown))
        If Not IsError(cel) Then
            strDestinationSheet = cel.Value
            cel.Offset(0, -31).Resize(1, cel.CurrentRegion.Columns.Count).Copy
            N = Sheets(strDestinationSheet).Cells(Sheets(strDestinationSheet).Rows.Count, "AF").End(xlUp).Row
            Sheets(strDestinationSheet).Cells(N + 1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
    Next cel
End With
```